# Custom ArrayAdapter (Array list) saved on SharePreferences

Tags: java, android, arraylist, sharedpreferences, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to save an Array List in my program. The list contains URLs that the user has visited or loaded into the WebView. I have done some research and it is possible but out of the >50 posts I have read regarding it none of them seems to work. I believe that if I add a method of sorts to the CustomArrayAdapter, then I will be able to do it but considering I'm a novice at this and my "Mentor" stopped mentoring me for some reason I can't figure it out. I have tried creating a SaveList and AddList method but both ended in failure even after spending 2-3 days working on these methods.

The end goal is that onPause is invoked it will save the list and when onStart is invoked it will add the list back. The only time it will come up blank is if the user clears the list. Thank you for your help in advance and if there is a smarter more efficient way of doing this then don't hesitate to come forward and suggest the idea. Eventually, I would like someone to review the program and help make it "less code" and have a more professional layout regarding the code.

Also sorry in advance if this is a repeated question I cannot find a way that works, as well as if I'm calling "method" by the wrong term I intend to mean as an example (public void saveLise(){}). I have just started to figure out ActivityLifeCycle and saving information within it.

main activity,

@Override

```
protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    Log.d("lifecycle","onStart invoked");

    SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    Url = settings.getString("curURL", "");


    if(!Url.matches("https://www.google.ca")
            || !Url.matches("https://www.google.com")){
        mWebView.loadUrl(Url);
    }
    mWebView.loadUrl(urlHomepage);

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.d("lifecycle","onPause invoked");
    Url = mWebView.getUrl();

    SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString("curURL", Url);

    editor.apply();
}
```

CustomArray Adapter:

```
public class UrlHistoryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private final Context context;
private final List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

public UrlHistoryAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;


}
public void addItem(String item) {
    this.list.add(item);
}
public void deleteItem(String item) {
    this.list.remove(item);
}
public void deleteList(){
   list.clear();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();

}
@Override
public String getItem(int position) {
    return list.get(position);
}
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
@SuppressLint("InflateParams")
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.preference_list_item, parent, false);
    }
    TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.title);
    textView.setText(getItem(position));

    return view;
}


}
```

Comment: Your requirment is save arraylist in SharedPreferences..?

Comment: @Tarunkonda yes it is

Answer (score 0):

Saving and retrieving the ArrayList From SharedPreference

```
        public static void addToPreference(String id,Context context) {
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(Constants.MyPreference, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            ArrayList<String> list = getListFromPreference(context);
            if (!list.contains(id)) {
                list.add(id);
                SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sharedPreferences.edit();
                Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
                set.addAll(list);
                edit.putStringSet(Constant.LIST, set);
                edit.commit();

            }
        }
        public static ArrayList<String> getListFromPreference(Context context) {
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(Constants.MyPreference, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            Set<String> set = sharedPreferences.getStringSet(Constant.LIST, null);
            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            if (set != null) {
                list = new ArrayList<>(set);
            }
            return list;
        }
```

Comment: How would i implement this as in to what file and where

Comment: Thank you for the feedback though